# what are pros and cons to define constant local variables as static ( c++)?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

```
void Animation::playAnimation() const
{
    static const int index = 0;
    const std::string& animationFileName = m_animationContainer.getAnimationName(index);
    static const int zOrder = -1;
    static bool isLooping = false;

    AnimationBank::play(animationFileName,
                        zOrder,
                        isLooping);
}
```

what are pros and cons to define constant local variables as static?
what is an overhead of defining `index`, `zOrder`, `isLooping` as `static`. Is there any benefit to do this?

Comment: Under optimizations? Probably irrelevant whether they're static or not.

Comment: No runtime overhead. static variables are stored in the Data section in the process address space.

Comment: any benefit? is it worth to write

Comment: @FaceBro So there is potential overhead. Loading from memory to registers.

Comment: @freakish yep, every bit has its own overhead in this sense. by no overhead I mean no significant overhead against stack based variable

Comment: @FaceBro These variables can potentially be stored in registers directly, not necesserly on stack. While with static variables they have to be loaded to registers in runtime. Whether this is significant or not totally depends on what you are trying to achieve, on your cpu and thousand other factors. Probably it doesn't matter. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @freakish in this particular case the aim to make them static to prevent them creating and destroyed on each function.

Comment: @freakish hmm, good to know this. is this a common optimization piece? in c we need the register keyword to achieve what you described, not sure of cpp case

Comment: I have modified the question as follows
what are pros and cons to define constant local variables as static?
what is an overhead of defining `index`, `zOrder`, `isLooping` as `static`. Is there any benefit to do this?

Comment: @FaceBro If your compiler doesn't cache stuff in registers without the `register` keyword, you should probably use a different compiler

Comment: Please don't cross-post. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350501/is-there-any-benefit-to-to-define-constant-local-variables-as-static-c.

Comment: @PasserBy Good to know, thanks for the info .

Answer (score 5):

In general case if you declare a static variable inside of a function then it will be initialized during first use. In order to achieve this behavior another global static variable of boolean type will be created by the compiler. It will be initially set to `false` and then set to `true` after related static variable is initialized.

In your case there is no point to declare any variables as static.

Comment: I have modified the question as follows
what are pros and cons to define constant local variables as static?
what is an overhead of defining `index`, `zOrder`, `isLooping` as `static`. Is there any benefit to do this?

Comment: The standards only require that a static which is local to a block (a function body is a type of block) be initialised before first use - which typically amounts to being at **or before** the block is entered for the first time. There is nothing stopping it being initialised sooner (e.g. at program startup), which means using another static flag is unnecessary (but not forbidden).

Comment: @Peter you are wrong, standard 6.7 Declaration statement [stmt.dcl] : "Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is performed **the first time control passes through its  declaration**; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization..."

Comment: That's only true C++11 and later.  It was not true in earlier C++ standards.

Comment: Well, this post is tagged as C++11 and C++14 so I guess there is no point to discuss older standards.

Comment: It is also tagged C++, along with those, which can refer to any C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have a little bit overhead when using static variables in function, since each time your program execute that function it has to check whether these static variables initialized.

Comment: I have modified the question as follows
what are pros and cons to define constant local variables as static?
what is an overhead of defining `index`, `zOrder`, `isLooping` as `static`. Is there any benefit to do this?

Comment: They're different, `static variable` will remain after the function exit, but `local variable` will be destroyed (you can search about auto variables), `const local variable` only add the `const` attribute to it. Did you mean `global variable` ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the easy one.

**const:**

const doesn't give you any ovehead and the only advantage it give you is the variable can't be changed during its life time. It is interesting because:

Correctness.

If want a that show clearly show what the variable, use const make clear that variable won't/can't be changed.

You may think, why I don't use a #define for example. Well, define will make the compiler replace it to fix values and in some cases it is not and advantage like strings or objects.

Protection.

If someone else qill use your function you make clear this variable can be changed and you protect its value.

**Static:**

Static give you a overhead because after create the variable for the first time it will exist during the lifetime of your program and the advantage is exactly that. When the variable is create you give it an value. Because it stay alive after that, no matter what happens, it can't get again a value as it the is the  first time.

Lets see an example with class.

Suppose you want a class to manager an addition to one int and this int need to accumulate this additions including a new object of this class is created and or destroyed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class ClassAcInt {
      public:
             void Print_iVar();
             void Add_iVar();
      private:
             static int iVar;
};

int ClassAcInt::iVar = 10;           //iVar = 10

void ClassAcInt::Print_iVar() {      //Show iVar
     cout << iVar << '\n';
}

void ClassAcInt::Add_iVar() {        //Add 1 to iVar
     iVar++;
}

int main () {
    ClassAcInt* oC1 = new ClassAcInt();     //iVar = 10
    oC1->Print_iVar();                      //print iVar
    oC1->Add_iVar();                        //iVar = iVar + 1
    oC1->Print_iVar();                      //Print iVar
    delete oC1;                             //Bye what we did... Are you sure?

    ClassAcInt* oC2 = new ClassAcInt();     //iVar = 10? Are you sure?
    oC2->Print_iVar();                      //Print iVar.... What a hack!!!!
    oC2->Add_iVar();                        //iVar = iVAr + 1
    oC2->Print_iVar();                      //omgosh...
    delete oC2;
}
```

You can think the result will be:
10
11
10
11

but 'surprisingly' the result is:
10
11
11
12

The key is the lines static int iVar; and int ClassAcInt::iVar = 10;. Try to suppress the static word and see what happens :)